# Get Java error when sending emails via Amazon SES

Tags: java, matlab, smtp

I tried to send emails via Amazon SES in Matlab. It worked well 2 months ago but now it gave the following java error:

Error using sendmail (line 164)

Exception reading response;
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested
target

The matlab code is attached

```
myaddress = 'myemail@gmail.com';
username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
mypassword = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

setpref('Internet','E_mail',myaddress);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username',username);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password',mypassword);

props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class', ...
                  'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','465');

title = 'I am testing';
content = 'I am not sure if you can receive my email.';
email_address = 'targetemail@gmail.com';

sendmail(email_address, title, content);
```

Comment: If i change the smtp server to 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' then it will give the error "connection reset". please help

Comment: It looks like Amazon changed/updated their SSL certificate.  For some reason the certificate cannot be validated.  I suggest asking over on the Amazon forums.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer for myself. Hope it will help to other people who may have the same issue.
"TURN OFF ANTI-VIRUS software" and all good now.

Comment: Thanks. I just got the issue with Avast! Antivirus. I disabled SSL email analysis and the exception evaporated.